# How do I find which form input is focused out?

Tags: jquery

I have to find which element is focused out and I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#registration_form input").each(function(){
        $(this).focusout('click',function(){   
        $name = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log($name);         
        });
});
```

Is this the right way to get the name of the input  that has the focused out action or you know a better way??  thanks

Comment: Use the `blur` handler: `$("#registration_form input").blur(function() { console.log($(this).prop('name') });`

Comment: @h2ooooooo, Why don't you convert your comment to answer. You would have got +1

Comment: @Satpal I'd feel silly posting super short answers. If I want to post a short answer or just hints/code I usually do it in the comments. :) Someone with more time would be able to describe the reasoning for changing it out to `blur`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#registration_form input").focusout(function () {
        var name = this.name;
        console.log(name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   $("#registration_form input").focusout(function() {
            alert($(this).prop('name'));
   });
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y99SF/1/)

There are a bit difference b/w `.focusout()` and `.blur()` event. [Read More](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/jquery-focusout-and-blur-event-differences/)

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element
>   inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in
>   that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in
>   other words, it supports event bubbling).

[**Example - API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)